# Invalid Template Error passing class function using Boost

Tags: c++, templates, boost

Trying to using a template, where the argument is

```
template<class T, boost::function<long (T*)> &f>
static long myFunc(const vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>>   &inputVector)   
{ // do stuff}
```

This is the call I make

```
long i = myFunc<MyClass, boost::bind(&MyClass::myClassFunc, _1)>(myInputVector);
```

where the signature of the function is

```
long myClassFunc() const { return m_value; }
```

Getting the following compiler error:

error C2975: 'f' : invalid template argument for 'myFunc', expected compile-time constant expression

What do I need to get this to compile?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You neither pass any instance of MyClass nor myClassFunc takes T* as an argument, this code doesn't make any sense regardless of issues with template arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding arguments to a function is a run-time operation. When you pass a value as a template parameter, the value has to be known at compile time. Pass the boost::function as an argument.

```
template<class T>
static long myFunc(const vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>> &inputVector, boost::function<long (T*)> &f)   
{ // do stuff 
}
```

call it like that:

```
long i = myFunc<MyClass)>(myInputVector, boost::bind(&MyClass::myClassFunc, _1));
```